# How to see number representation in floating point binary

Tags: java, c++, binary

For example, I have the number `0.1`:

```
double n = 0.1;
```

It's represented in **IEEE-754** big endian as:

```
0 01111111011 1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
```

How can I output `0.1` in this binary format?

Comment: u can use `Float.floatToIntBits` method

Comment: @Survivor - "You can use" - also this has already been said in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a double to binary you'll need to call `Double.doubleToLongBits(x)` and `Long.toBinaryString(x)`.

So you could try `String binary = Long.toBinaryString( Double.doubleToLongBits(0.1) );`

To get a full 64-bit representation you'd then have to prepend as many 0s as needed.

**Edit**:

Since you asked for a C version, I'll try and add one (though I'm no C expert so I might miss something like std lib functions):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

union binary {
    double d;
    uint64_t l;
} binary;

int main() {
    union binary b;
    b.d = 0.1; //set the value as double

    uint64_t bin = b.l; //read the value as 64-bit unsigned integer

    char c[65];
    c[64] = '\0'; //string terminator
    //iterate from 63 to 0
    for( int i = sizeof(uint64_t) * 8 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if( bin & 1 ) {
            c[i]='1';
        } else {
            c[i]='0';
        }

        bin >>= 1; //right-shift by 1, i.e. 0010 -> 0001 etc.
    }                                                                                                                                             
    printf("%s\n",c);

    return 0;
}
```

This basically uses a union struct that allows you to write a double and access the bytes as a 64-bit unsigned integer (aka long long). Then the code iterates over a copy of that integer, checks whether the last bit is set and sets the according element of the character array and finally right-shifts the bits by 1.

Note that with some pointer casting you could do the same without the union structure: `double dbl = 0.1; uint64_t bin = *((uint64_t*)(&dbl));` (You'd need a variable here to have something to point to, alternatively provide a function and take a pointer to the parameter).

A final warning though: you'll have to make sure that the data types you're using have equal size (i.e. they map to exactly the same memory location) or otherwise you'll run into access violations or other unpleasant stuff.

Comment: great, thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Maybe you know how to do the same in `C`?

Comment: @Maximus I can't check C for now and I'm no professional C user but I'd probably try a pointer cast or union struct to get the bytes for the number and then check each bit individually by looping and shifting.

Comment: @Maximus I tried an online C compiler and I'll add a version that _should_ work or at least get you started. You might add the `C` tag for consistency though.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I've added `C` and `C++` tags to the question.

Answer (score 5):

Float class can do that for you calling the method `Float.floatToIntBits`

```
final int intBits = Float.floatToIntBits(4.1f);
final String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(intBits);
System.out.println(binary);
```

here can you verify setting the fusses i the binary result...

https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Comment: Worth noting that this doesn't print leading zeros to make it 32 bits wide. You'd need to add those yourself.

Comment: thanks, it ouputted `111101110011001100110011001101` for `0.1`, which is not the same as what I've shown in my question. Most likely it's used 32 bit format, how can I get the same for 64 bit formal?

Comment: @Maximus, try with `Double.doubleToLongBits(0.1)` and `Long.toBinaryString()`.

Comment: @Thomas, can you post it as an answer?